# Limit Django data to current user

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

Hoping you can help me.

I am trying to run the below - for ONLY the current requesting user. But it pulls back the data for all users.

Can you help me to figure out why that is?

```
open_tasks = skills.objects.filter(creator=request.user).raw('''
            SELECT *, round(((closed_points)/(open_points+closed_points)*100),2) as points_pct,
            round(((closed_count)/(open_count+closed_count)*100),2) as closed_pct from (
            SELECT id, sum(open_points) as open_points, sum(closed_points) as closed_points, sum(open_count) as open_count, sum(closed_count) as closed_count
            from (
            SELECT id, 
            case when status = 'open' then sum(points) end as open_points,
            case when status <> 'open' then sum(points) end as closed_points,
            case when status = 'open' then sum(count) end as open_count,
            case when status <> 'open' then sum(count) end as closed_count
            from (
            SELECT category as id, status, sum(cast(points as int)) as points, count(*) as count 
            FROM voximisa_skills group by category, status)s
            group by id, status)p
            group by id)j
            ''')
```

Comment: The `.filter(..)` will not work if you perform a `.raw(...)` query. You will thus have to filter in the raw queyr.

Comment: I tried to add where user = ''' + str(request.user) + ''' but I get an error. Let's say the username is bob, it will say column BOB does not exist

Comment: don't do that! Never inject data in the SQL string, you should use the parameter to do this. This will prevent SQL injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the Django documentation on [**`raw(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#raw) says:

> `raw()` always triggers a **new query** and doesn’t account for previous filtering. As such, it should generally be called from the `Manager` or from a fresh `QuerySet` instance.

You thus should include the user filtering in the raw query with:

```
open_tasks = skills.objects.filter(creator=request.user).raw('''
            SELECT *, round(((closed_points)/(open_points+closed_points)*100),2) as points_pct,
            round(((closed_count)/(open_count+closed_count)*100),2) as closed_pct from (
            SELECT id, sum(open_points) as open_points, sum(closed_points) as closed_points, sum(open_count) as open_count, sum(closed_count) as closed_count
            from (
            SELECT id, 
            case when status = 'open' then sum(points) end as open_points,
            case when status <> 'open' then sum(points) end as closed_points,
            case when status = 'open' then sum(count) end as open_count,
            case when status <> 'open' then sum(count) end as closed_count
            from (
            SELECT category as id, status, sum(cast(points as int)) as points, count(*) as count 
            FROM voximisa_skills
            WHERE creator_id=%s
            GROUP BY category, status)s
            group by id, status)p
            group by id)j''',
        [request.user.pk]
    )
```

Here we make use of the [parameters that we can pass to the query [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#passing-parameters-into-raw). One should *not* format the SQL string with the data, since that can result in [*SQL injection* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Thanks a lot - I've tried it, but this also does not limit it to only the current user :(

Comment: @kikee1222: did you add `WHERE creator_id=%s` to the query...

Comment: Ah sorry - I didn't refresh the view. I've done this - the creator column in my dataset is the username. not the userid. So, if I change it to str([request.user]) then i get  'not all arguments converted during string formatting'

Comment: @kikee1222: *don't* call `str` on the list! You should call it on the item, or better: use `request.user.username`, so `[request.user.username]`.

Comment: @kikee1222: furthermore you should use a `ForeignKey` if you refer to another model. Not a simple `CharField`: `CharField`s can not guarantee referential integrity.